# Debian packaging - treatment of modified/created files, debian/rules

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I've a couple of questions regarding treatment of files produced during the build of a library that I want to package under Ubuntu.  I'm using the dh_make infrastructure, so I get a "debian" folder with various scripts in etc.

(1) I'd like to modify a library Makefile before the build takes place so that it has a reference to $(CURDIR) in it (to ensure that stuff is installed to the right folder).  Normally I would pass this to a configure script or similar, but this file is hard-coded, so I'm trying to change it via the debian/rules script.  (Is this even the right way of doing it?)  I'm having problems as it then wants the change checked in, even though it is only a temporary file.  Can I mark the file as temporary?

(2) The build itself takes a very long time, and only once it is complete do I find out if my changes worked.  Can I tell the packing infrastructure to suspend checks and just continue from the last point?  It currently cleans everything, or if I stop it cleaning things, it'll complain that there are loads of extra files lying around.  (I understand the checks are useful, but I don't want to wait an hour to discover I've made a spelling mistake.)  Can I tell it to ignore anything extra temporarily?

Comment: There's a command line option "-nc" that stops dpkg_buildpackage from doing a clean before building, which solves (2).

Answer (score 0):

debian rules works just like a normal Makefile, so all you have to do to is alter the relevant build rules in it

1) figure out where it builds the library and just before that insert a line that runs some command (sed maybe?) to modify the other Makefile.  If you just need to pass some parameter into the other make file make will take variables just like shell does

2) figure out what is being run late in the build and what target is being used and just run that target.  make -vf debian/rules might be useful for working out what is happening

have fun...

Comment: The issue is that if I modify a file it wants to build a patch file for that change.  I need to mark the file somehow as being modifiable during the build - is there a way of doing this?